# C# Add binarysecuritytoken and security tag to an XML SOAP document

Tags: c#, xml, soap

I have an `XmlDocument` object. How can I add a token to the document so the output will contain the following XML?

I could just add the element with the *base64* encoded value generated from the exported certificate but that seems less than ideal.

```
<wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
     <wsse:BinarySecurityToken EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509PKIPathv1" wsu:Id="X509-1AFD1B43221516987374001369">{encoded token}</wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
</wsse:Security>
```

Comment: How exactly would you generate the token value from certificate?